# Double Line space in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a weird line spacing issue in Visual Studio (irrespective of VS version. I have tried VS2010 and VS2013). The code files in one particular solution open with an "Inconsistent Line Endings" warning and no matter what option I choose in that dialog, the code file opens with double line space between every line of code. The same code file when opened in Notepad shows up fine. Please see the attached screenshots.

I have tried many of the solutions that google could throw at me and none have worked so far :-(

Notepad Screenshot:

[image: .cs file while opened in Notepad]

VS Screenshot:

[image: Same file while opened in VS2010 or VS2013]

**UPDATE**: Wordpad screenshot

[image]

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Notepad is useless for line-endings. Use Wordpad instead.

Comment: Well, with wordpad the code is almost unreadable. I have added a third screenshot in the question

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this in VS2013.

After changing the inconsistent line endings to Windows CR LF, VisualStudio inserted CR LF CR LF everywhere, resulting in double spacing.  This became clear to me when I opened the file in Notepad++ and selected 'show all characters'.

I replaced all \n\r\n\r with \n\r, once, in Notepad++.  This seemed to fix things.